# Non-experimental implementation for experimental trait?

Tags: rust

I am wondering how it is possible that the compiler lets me do the following without even showing a warning:

```rust
let text = vec![ "hello", "world" ];
let joined = text.join( " " );
```

It works as expected. However, the documentation of [`std::slice::Join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.Join.html) says that this is a "nightly-only experimental API". Shouldn't the compiler complain? I don't have a nightly toolchain installed.

Comment: Vec has a join function

Answer (score 4):

You're calling [`Vec<T>::join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.join) (which comes from [`[T]::join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.join) via `Vec<T>`'s `Deref<Target=[T]>` implementation), which has been stable since Rust 1.3.0.

Comment: Oh you are right. I tried a few variations and accidently copied the wrong line. However, it still works when I remove the `vec!`. Also, `Vec<T>::join()` just uses the `Join` trait.

Comment: @FlorianKusche The `join` you're calling isn't coming from a `impl Join` block. It's just a free-standing method that happens to have the same name. The `Join` trait isn't stable. That current implementation of the `join` method uses the  `Join` trait behind the scenes is an implementation detail.

Comment: To put it another way: the method `join` _predates_ the existence of the `Join` trait. Older implementations of `join` do not reference the `Join` trait.  Whether you can use `Vec<T>::join` is entirely unrelated to the `Join` trait.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::slice::join` does reference the unstable `Join` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.join). However, the Rust standard library does frequently use unstable features, and is allowed to do so even in the stable release of Rust.

Since your code doesn't reference the unstable `Join` trait at all, Rust accepts it.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried to implement `Join` on an own class and immediately got the expected error. (use of unstable library feature 'slice_concat_trait'...) Is it considered safe to use such functions in production code? I think it should be, because even `Vec<T>::join()` does it.

Comment: @FlorianKusche It's up to you if you accept the risks. First off, from that point on, you (and your dependents) must use a nightly compiler. Also, there is (currently) no clear distincition between features that are incomplete and complete but might change or get removed. The fact that `std` uses it internally does not imply stability.

Comment: @FlorianKusche If you're asking whether `slice.join` is safe to use, it is - it's marked as stable and existing stable Rust code uses it, so the Rust dev team will not break code that uses it. If you're asking about the the Join trait or other unstable code, then no.